# How to use PostgreSQL to calculate the completion time of two timestamp records?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an invitations table with the following fields:

```
Invitations: id, created_at, completed_at
```

I am working to write a PostgreSQL query that breaks down the data by weekly cohorts (last 7 days) and show the average completion time (the difference between created_at and completed_at in days). FYI, it's possible for completed_at to be null, meaning not completed.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT  TRUNC(DATE_PART('day', CURRENT_DATE - i.created_at )/7)  AS weeks_ago,
                date(min(i.created_at)) AS "Date Start",
                date(max(i.created_at)) AS "Date End",
                count(DISTINCT i.id) AS "Total Num Invites",
                TIMESTAMPDIFF('day', i.created_at, i.completed_at)    
FROM invitations i
GROUP BY weeks_ago
ORDER BY weeks_ago ASC;
```

This is erroring with:

```
ERROR:  function timestampdiff(unknown, timestamp without time zone, timestamp without time zone) does not exist
LINE 5:     TIMESTAMPDIFF('day', i.created_at, i.completed_at)
            ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
, Time: 0.085000s
```

I'm using PostgreSQL, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: *what am I doing wrong here?* Perhaps calling a function that doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TIMESTAMPDIFF is not natural of PostgreSQL. See here: [Postgresql date/time functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html).

In PostgreSQL, date operations are like number operations.

Example:

```
SELECT '2020-01-05 00:01:05'::timestamp - '2020-01-02 00:05:05'::timestamp
-- you get: 2 days 23:56:00
```

So, to simulate `TIMESTAMPDIFF(SQL_TSI_DAY, i.created_at, i.completed_at)` you have to do:

```
DATE_PART('day', i.completed_at - i.created_at)
```

Wiht the previous example you have:

```
SELECT DATE_PART('day', '2020-01-05 00:01:05'::timestamp-'2020-01-02 00:05:05'::timestamp)
-- you get: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Your biggest hint is `ERROR:  function timestampdiff(unknown,`. This is telling you that it does not know what datatype the value you are giving the function is. TIMESTAMPDIFF() requires the first parameter to be one of a defined list of constants. In your case SQL_TSI_DAY, like:

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(SQL_TSI_DAY, i.created_at, i.completed_at)
```

[This link](https://docs.intersystems.com/irislatest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RSQL_timestampdiff) might be helpful. It gives some details on the TIMESTAMPDIFF() function.

EDIT: Replaced the link above. The first link I posted had some typos and incorrect data.